# Scaling Flex object causes rotation to act strangely

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, rotation, scale

When I have an object in a Flex container (absolute positioning) and set its scale value very low, then rotate it, the rotation gets 'choppier' as the scale decreases. I'm including code that reproduces the problem. You can hit 'up arrow' to scale down the object ('down' to scale up) and 'page up' to increase the size of the object so you can still see it. After scaling it down, you can use 'left' and 'right' to rotate it. Notice when the object is not scaled down it rotates cleanly, but if you scale the object way down (while increasing the size of the object so you can still see it), the rotation gets choppy. Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:test="com.test.*"
                   resize="onResize()" addedToStage="onStart()" removedFromStage="onEnd()">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable]
        private var _rotation:Number = 0;

        [Bindable]
        private var _scale:Number = 1;

        [Bindable]
        private var _blockSize:Number = 100;

        protected function onStart():void {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
        }

        protected function onEnd():void {
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
        }

        protected function onResize():void {
            if (Layer) {
                Layer.x = width/2
                Layer.y = height/2;
            }
        }

        protected function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
                Layer.rotation += -1;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
                Layer.rotation += 1;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) {
                Layer.scaleX = Layer.scaleY = (Layer.scaleX / 2);
            }
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
                Layer.scaleX = Layer.scaleY = (Layer.scaleX * 2);
            }
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.PAGE_UP) {
                _blockSize *=2;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.PAGE_DOWN) {
                _blockSize /=2;
            }
            this._rotation = Layer.rotation;
            this._scale = Layer.scaleX;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:SkinnableContainer id="Layer">
    <test:RotatedComponent width="{_blockSize}" height="{_blockSize}"/>
</s:SkinnableContainer>
<s:Label x="10" y="10" text="Rotation: {_rotation}"/>
<s:Label x="10" y="30" text="Scale: {_scale}"/>
<s:Label x="10" y="50" text="Block: {_blockSize}"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Code for RotatedComponent.mxml

```
package com.test {

import mx.core.UIComponent;

public class RotatedComponent extends UIComponent {

    public function RotatedComponent() {
        super();
    }

    override public function set width(value:Number):void {
        super.width = value;
        this.x = - (width/2);
    }

    override public function set height(value:Number):void {
        super.height = value;
        this.y = - (height/2);
    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
        graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x333333);
        graphics.beginFill(0x660000);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        graphics.endFill();
        graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xffffff);
        graphics.drawCircle(unscaledWidth/2, unscaledHeight/2, 5);
    }
}
}
```

Thanks!
Derek

Comment: +1 for providing a runnable sample.  Although the behavior you describe is kind of what I would expect. I thought bitmaps were created and used under the hood for rotating; so the smaller the bitmap the less "clear" I would expect the processed result to be. [However, ActionScript image manipulation is not my area of expertise so I could be wrong]

Comment: Thanks! To me, it seems more like a rounding issue of some sort under the covers since the component rotates cleanly when at a higher scale. The really weird part is that (at least in my real application) the underlying matrix is not changing every time rotation is changed when scale gets very small. When the matrix does get updated, the object on the screen finally shows the rotation which results in the "racheting" look to rotation.

Comment: To be specific, when you get the scale down to around .0003 or below, the behavior starts happening. Rotation is jerky and appears to intermittently affect scaling as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can officially be called a bug. If I calculate the matrix for the transformation rather than setting component.scale() and component.rotation() the results are correct. My best guess is that there are rounding errors somewhere in the code underneath the Flex setters (I stepped through all the Flex code and nothing weird was going on). So the short answer:

Instead of:

```
component.scaleX = component.scaleY = _scale;
component.rotation = _rotation;
```

Use

```
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.scale(_scale, _scale);
matrix.rotate(_rotation * Math.PI / 180);
component.transform.matrix = matrix;
```

Hope that helps!
Derek